# Open and Close one Expandable Item in ListView - React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of Messages that you should be able to click and expand more for info. At the moment, my implementation expands/collapses all messages by clicking on any message.

[image: Collapsed View]

[image: Expanded View]

Within each Tab Component I populate it as such:

```
  tabContent =  (x, i) => <View style={{height: this.state.height}}>
    <List onLayout={({nativeEvent: {layout: {height}}}) => {
      this.heights[i] = height;
      if (this.state.activeTab === i) this.setState({height})
    }} >
         {
            new Array(x).fill(null).map((_, i) => <Item key={i}>
               <View>
                 <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
                 <Text>Message {i}</Text>
                 </TouchableOpacity>
                 <Expand value={this.state.open}>
                   <Text>
                     Body of Message
                   </Text>
                 </Expand>
                </View>
             </Item>
          )}

     </List>
   </View>

heights = [500, 500];
state = {
  activeTab: 0,
  height: 500
};
```

What is causing them all to expand/collapse at once and how can i change that to only expand/collapse the Item that is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have some `activeIndex` in the state and check that to expand and collapse the appropriate `View`. For example,

In you state

```
...
this.state={
  open: false,
  activeIndex: 0
}
...
```

When you render your view, you can check for `activeIndex`

```
...
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open, activeIndex: i })}>
...
<Expand value={(this.state.activeIndex === i) && this.state.open}>
..
```

Hope this gives you some idea.

Comment: Ignore that, Ok it sort of works but clicking on a separate message will collapse an opened one and then I have to click it again.

Comment: Yes according to above logic, only one will open at a time